# why `local_rank` is zero in DDP even I set visible CUDA as 2?

Tags: pytorch, cuda, gpu, distributed-computing

There are 3 GPUs in my system.

I want to run on the last one i.e. 2. For this reason, I set `gpu_id` as 2 in my configuration file as well as `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2`. But in my program, the following line always assigns the 0th GPU.

```
        local_rank = torch.distributed.get_rank()
        torch.cuda.set_device(local_rank)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I don’t think there is an issue to fix — Pytorch is enumerating the available GPUs from zero.

Comment: What is the [`torch.distributed.get_world_size()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html?highlight=world_size#torch.distributed.get_world_size)? I think you'll find out it is 1, and not 3 as you might be expecting...

Comment: @Shai It is coming as 1. Does it mean my tensors are stored on CUDA 2 only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2` you tell the OS to only expose the third GPU to your process. That is, as far as PyTorch is concerned, there is only one GPU. Therefore [`torch.distributed.get_world_size()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html?highlight=world_size#torch.distributed.get_world_size) returns `1` (and not 3).
The rank of this GPU, in your process, will be 0 - since there are no other GPUs available for the process. But as far as the OS is concerned - all processing are done on the third GPU that was allocated to the job.